# USB 3.0 Debug Cable with a Type-A To Type-C Adapter

Tags: usb, short-circuit, debugging, windows, debugwire

I know that the USB 3.0 Debug Cable is just a standard USB 3.0 without the 5V supply line (VBUS).

I have a USB 3.0 Debug Cable Type-A to Type-A (in particular this one: [USB 3.0 Debug Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0032ANCBO)).

I need to connect this one to a computer, to proceed with WinDbg Kernel Debugging, which exposes a USB 3.0 Type-C (Debug is online to this port. I checked with usbview.exe).

To do this I need to buy an adapter from Type-A to Type-C for one extremity of the cable.

**Can I buy any Type-A to Type-C Adapter or need a special one?** (This one could be ok? [USB Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08HZ6PS61))

I'm asking this because I know that, in general, a cable with two host interfaces can damage the hosts if the power line (VBUS) isn't correctly handled.

Comment: The debug cable does not have the VBUS pins connected. Why do you expect any damage to occur?